# How to compare a string value with the Table Column Values?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to compare a string value with the list of table column values and return true if all the values matches the string

```
Table A:
BM  BG1 1   
BM  BG8 2   
BM  BG2 3   
BM  BG1 4   

String :BG1
```

I have to compare the string `BG1` with the second column values and if all the values matches it, I should return `true` else I should return `false`.

Comment: Does your table have 3 columns or is `BM BG1 1` stored in a single column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Conditional Aggregate` to check the `count`

Try something like this

```
declare @string varchar(100) = 'BG1'

SELECT CASE
         WHEN Sum(CASE
                    WHEN col2 = @string THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                  END) = Count(*) THEN 'TRUE'
         ELSE 'FALSE'
       END
FROM   TableA
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.It helped me